# Istio outbound traffic sent to Inbound listener

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio

I have noticed that when running docker inside of docker whilst using Istio on Kubernetes, traffic sent from the "nested" container gets lost.

HTTP requests from a container using the bridge network will show up in istio-proxy logs as "inboundPassthroughClusterIpv4", and will timeout after 10s. This implies to me that the outbound traffic is somehow getting sent to the inbound listener, where it then gets lost.

I noticed that when instructing my "nested" container to use the host network rather than bridge, everything behaves as normal, so i'm assuming this is some intricacy with how the iptables rules decide which traffic goes to which listener, but I could be way off the mark...

It's worth note that this setup used to work in Istio 1.4, but stopped working when upgrading to Istio 1.5.

Does anyone know what actually may be going on here? I have solved my problem, but now i'm just interested on what's causing this behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: Since istio 1.5 mtls is enabled by default on strict mode, so this might be the issue here. Your ¨nested¨ container is in istio injected namespace or outside the istio mesh?

Comment: We had configured mtls on 1.4 so there shouldn't be any differences there. The top level container is running in a pod in an istio injected namespace, then the "nested" container is running inside of that container.